# Using multiple copy buffers in Bash

Tags: bash, clipboard, readline, buffer

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> cuts text from current location to the beginning of line.

Now, I can paste this with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> whenever I want **until** the next time I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> to copy another line in the buffer.

Now the problem I want to solve is that I want to have multiple copy buffers of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> that I could use for later use

What are the ways I could achieve this with keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever you get into killring is there. Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> to yank and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> to rotate the yank.

The function is called yank-pop. You can find it in man pages [readline(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/readline)